# SQL query to Lambda Expression C#

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, lambda

SQL query:

```
SELECT M.MailItemId, m.Subject, ISNULL(m.SendCC, ''), ISNULL(attachments.counter, 0) Counters, M.CreationDate
FROM MailItem AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MailItemId, COUNT(MailItemId) counter
    FROM Attachment Group By MailItemId
) AS attachments ON M.MailItemId = attachments.MailItemId
```

There are two models MailItem and Attachment.
MailItemId is primary key in MailItem and foreign key in Attachment model.
Want to convert above query to a lambda expression.

Comment: Please don't undo the editing... it was unreabable without being formatted.

Comment: What have you tried so far with Linq? Show us your code and entity model etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a table of `MailItems` and a table of `Attachments`. There is a straightforward one-to-many relation between `MailItems` and `Attachments`: every `MailItem` has zero or more `Attachments`, and every `Attachment` belongs to exactly one `MailItem`, namely the `MailItem` that the foreign key refers to.

Quite often, people want "MailItems with their Attachments", they don't want a left outer join:

- MailItem 1 with Attachments A, C
- MailItem 2 with Attachments B, D, F
- MailItem 3 without Attachments
- MailItem 4 with Attachment E

You on the other hand, seem to prefer the following result:

```
MailItem Attachment
    1        A
    2        B
    1        C
    3      <null>
    4        E
    2        D
    2        F
```

This solution is seldom wanted. That's why there is no standard LINQ method for it.

To get MailItems with their Attachment, use GroupJoin. If you want the left outer join, use SelectMany after the GroupJoin.

### MailItems with their Attachments

```
var mailItemsWithTheirAttacments = dbContext.MailItems.GroupJoin(
dbContext.Attachments,                         // GroupJoin MailItems with Attachments

mailitem => mailItem.MailItemId,               // from every MailItem take the primary key
attachment => attachment.MailItemId,           // from every Attachment take the foreign key

// parameter resultSelector: for every MainItem and all its Attachments
// make one new object
(mailItem, attachmentsOfThisMailItem) => new
{
    // Select the MailItem properties that you plan to use
    Id = mailItem.Id,
    Sender = mailItem.Sender,
    ...

    Attachments = attachmentsOfThisMailItem.Select(attachment => new
    {
         // Select only the Attachments properties that you plan to use:
         Id = attachment.Id,
         Format = attachment.Format,
         ...

         // not needed, you already know the value:
         // MailItemId = attachment.MailItemId,
    })
    .ToList(),
})
```

### Left Outer Join

```
var result = dbContext.MailItems.GroupJoin(dbContext.Attachments,
    mailitem => mailItem.MailItemId,
    attachment => attachment.MailItemId,
    (mailItem, attachmentsOfThisMailItem) => new
    {
         MailItem = mailItem,
         Attachments = attachmentsOfThisMailItem,
    })

    // make it a left outer join, using SelectMany
    .SelectMany(groupJoinResult => groupJoinResult.Attachments,

    (groupJoinResult, attachment) => new
    {
        MailId = groupJoinResult.MailItem.Id,
        Sender = groupJoinResult.MailItem.Sender,
        ...

        AttachmentId = attachment.Id,
        Format = attachment.Format,
        ...
    });
```

### Use the virtual ICollections

If you have followed the entity framework conventions, you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class MailItem
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    ...

    // every MailItem has zero or more Attachments (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments {get; set;}
}

class Attachment
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    ...

    // every Attachment belongs to exactly one MailItem, using foreign key:
    public int MailItemId {get; set;}
    public virtual MailItem MailItem {get; set;}
}
```

You might use other identifiers, but the important part are the virtual properties.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by the non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

The foreign key is a column in table Attachments. Hence property Attachment.MailItemId is not virtual. Property Attachment.MailItem represent the relation, hence it is virtual.

If you have defined the relations as properties, you can use them to do the GroupJoin or the Left Outer Join for you:

```
var mailItemsWithTheirAttachments = dbContext.MailItems.Select(mailItem => new
{
    Id = mailItem.Id,
    Sender = mailItem.Sender,
    ...

    Attachments = mailItem.Attachments
        .Where(attachment => ....)     // only if you don't want all Attachments
        .Select(attachment => new
        {
            Id = attachment.Id,
            ...
        })
        .ToList(),
});
```

Entity framework knows the relation, and will do the correct (group-)join for you.

IMHO this looks way more natural than a GroupJoin, whether or not followed by a selectMany